# Accessibility : screen reader , How to get the link indexes within scroll data grid to update from 1 when we scroll through

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a form that has data grid which turns into a scrolling table if the data row count increases beyond 6. The data rows are dynamically decided during run time based on input data.

While using screens reader tool, when i say 'click link' and i m at top of the table, it correctly identifies the link numbers from 1. When i scroll towards below numbers, the top link displayed is not 1, when i say click link again, the link numbers shows from 1 again correctly however in wrong position. Refer to screenshot attached.
Link 1 should be displayed against Misc not against appe*

[image]

Comment: This looks like the screen reader is simply drawing the link indicators in the wrong place, because of the y-offset of the scrolling pane.

Given that there are alternative ways to activate those links, it's not really an issue you need to fix, but you could report it to the screen reader vendor. A 'bare bones' example of the problem might help them resolve it.

Comment: What are the alternative ways? and what do you mean about y offset of the scrolling pane?

Comment: can we reset the y offset?

Comment: As the table scrolls, the y-offset changes (i.e. the top of the table goes above the top of its container. The problem here seems to be that the screen reader is not taking this into account (or is miscalculating it), But this is a fault of the screen reader, not you. Other screen readers may behave differently. I advise that you just report the issue to the screen reader vendor (perhaps link to this stack overflow question), and move on.